# how to copy and paste only a specific column in each file?

Tags: text-processing, paste

I have nearly 400 files, each looks like this:

```
head HI.1.Q091_13R_all_PA_code
Ha8_00040788 C
Ha4_00024045 C
Ha4_00025366 C
Ha16_00022130 C
Ha16_00023451 C
Ha8_00040789 C
Ha4_00025367 C
Ha4_00024046 A
Ha16_00022131 C
Ha16_00023452 C
```

I want to copy and paste only the "second" column of each file and save it as a tab-delimited file

```
head desired_output
C    C
C    A
C    C
C    C
C    C
C    A
C    A
A    A
C    A
C    C
```

Comment: Where does the 2nd column  come from?

Comment: Start with the `cut` command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**`paste`** + **`awk`** solution:

```
paste HI.* | awk '{ for(i=2; i<=NF; i+=2) printf "%s%s", $i, (i==NF? ORS : "\t") }' > result
```